# Notification alert service not working in controller getting typeError: Cannot read property 'alerts' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I have capturing the application response error ,while capturing the error, i am getting the error.

In Interceptor ,according to the response code , have assign the rootscope broadcast and show the alert  message in controller.
Here $rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired'); is assigning in interceptor and while capturing in service response inside controller.

```
$rootScope.$on("loginRequired", function(e) {
  alert("hello");
  alertsManager.addAlert('Yay!', 'alert-success');
});
```

**interceptor.**

```
var interceptor = function($q, alerts, $rootScope, $timeout, $location) {
  return {
    request: function(config) {
      console.log(config);
      return config;
    },
    response: function(response) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');
      return response || $q.when(response);
    },
    responseError: function(rejection) {
      if (rejection.status == 500) {
        $location.url('/ho');
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $rootScope.$broadcast('loginRequired');
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
      console.log(rejection.status);
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  }
};

$httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
```

**alertManagerfactory**

```
var alertsManager = function() {
  return {
    alerts: {},
    addAlert: function(message, type) {
      this.alerts[type] = this.alerts[type] || [];
      this.alerts[type].push(message);
    },
    clearAlerts: function() {
      for (var x in this.alerts) {
        delete this.alerts[x];
      }
    }
  };
};
alertsManager.$inject = [];
```

In controller :

```
var LoginController = function($scope, $rootScope, alerts, alertsManager) {

  $scope.alerts = alertsManager.alerts;
  // getting error in this line
  //getting typeError: Cannot read property 'alerts'  of undefined

  LoginService.AfterLogin(username, password)
    .then(function(response) {}, function(status) {
      console.log("Error" + status);
      if (status === 500) {
        $rootScope.$on("loginRequired", function(e) {
          alert("hello");
          alertsManager.addAlert('Yay!', 'alert-success');
        });
      }
    });
};
LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'alerts', 'alertsManager'];
```

In controller view.

```
<div ng-repeat="alert in alerts" ng-class="'alert-' + (alert.type || 'warning')" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

"this" keyword in your addAlert "method" is actually referencing anonymous function you have assigned to addAlert prop.

There are couple of ways to deal with this. For example creating variable that holds your object.

```
var alertsManager = function() {
  var $this = {
    alerts: {},
    addAlert: function(message, type) {
      $this.alerts[type] = $this.alerts[type] || [];
      $this.alerts[type].push(message);
    },
    clearAlerts: function() {
      for (var x in $this.alerts) {
        delete $this.alerts[x];
      }
    }
  };
  return $this;
};
alertsManager.$inject = [];
```